# Datatable Group by and sum one column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have this datatable:

```
RadkyData.Columns.Add("ČísloDokladuDodavatele", typeof(string));
            RadkyData.Columns.Add("Množství", typeof(string));
            RadkyData.Columns.Add("NákupníCena", typeof(string));
            RadkyData.Columns.Add("PřepočtováJednotka", typeof(string));
            RadkyData.Columns.Add("Přepočtovýkoeficient",
```

Comment: AsEnumerable, but i have error: AsEnumerable(System.Data.DataTable)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context C

Comment: Have you even tried one of the given asnwers?

Answer (score 0):

Just group the rows by `Col1, Col2,Col3` and `Sum()` up `Col4`

```
var input = new[] {
    new { Col1 =1, Col2= 2, Col3 = 1, Col4 = 1.5m},
    new { Col1 =1, Col2= 1, Col3 = 1, Col4 = 1.8m},
    new { Col1 =1, Col2= 2, Col3 = 1, Col4 = 2.5m},
    new { Col1 =1, Col2 =1, Col3 = 1, Col4 = 3m},
    new { Col1 =3, Col2 =1, Col3 = 4, Col4=  5m}
    };

var result = input.GroupBy(x => new { x.Col1, x.Col2, x.Col3 })
        .Select(x => new
        {
            Col1 = x.Key.Col1,
            Col2 = x.Key.Col2,
            Col3 = x.Key.Col3,
            Col4 = x.Sum(y => y.Col4)
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this using `Linq`.

```
    table.AsEnumerable()
         .Select(r=>new 
                    {
                        c1=r.Field<int>("col1"), 
                        c2 =r.Field<int>("col2"), 
                        c3 =r.Field<int>("col3"), 
                        c4 =r.Field<double>("col4")  
                    })
         .GroupBy(g=> new {g.c1, g.c2, g.c3})
         .Select(x=> new {
            col1 = x.Key.c1,
            col2 = x.Key.c2,
            col3 = x.Key.c3,
            Sum = x.Sum(s=>s.c4)
        });
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QRxVLX)

**Output:**

```
{ col1 = 1, col2 = 2, col3 = 1, Sum = 4 }
{ col1 = 1, col2 = 1, col3 = 1, Sum = 4.8 }
{ col1 = 3, col2 = 1, col3 = 4, Sum = 5 }
```

Comment: `Sum = x.Sum(s=>s.c4)`

Comment: Thanks, but i have problem...i have other colums Col5,Col6...but i need group only col1-col4 and select Col5 and 6...from first...

Comment: We can do that, if you don't want other columns remove from `Select` statements. Answer was written based on information you supplied in the question :-).

Comment: I need have all columns in select (in result)...Col1 - Col6, but sum only Col4 where Col1-Col3 are the same...

Comment: What if there are multiple values for col5 or col6 after you grouped in col1-3? If you can answer this that's what you want.

Comment: Good, then just include col5, col6 also in the group by field, later in `Select` statement just grab the value like `x.Key.c5` and `x.Key.c6`.

Comment: But if i havent Col4 in groupby i have error in select: 'AnonymousType#2' does not contain a definition for 'c4' and no extension method 'c4' accepting a first argument of type 'AnonymousType#2' could be found

Comment: Do you want to display `col4` as well? if that is the case we are back to same question, what do you do when you see multiple col4 values after grouping col1-3?

Comment: If Col1,Col2,Col3,Col5,Col6 are the same than sum Col4

Comment: ok, Let's say you have two `col4` values when you group on col1-3, so what do you want to display? Display first value? or display both by concatenation ?

Comment: When i have rows where is the Col1,Col2,Col3 are the same do one row with Col1,Col2,Col3 and sum of Col4...

Comment: @koky What was in the question is now deviating, so I suggest close this question choosing one best answer and open another question with complete details. If we deviate from what's been asked it might confuse people reaching this post with similar problem. Hope you understand what  I mean.

Comment: Hmm...if you read the question now and the answers written here they are completely different, I doubt experts return back to this page and update their answers. I strongly encourage revert your update add new question with the takeaway from this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work
    mytable.Columns.Add("col4",GetType(Integer),"Col1+Col2+Col3");